# How to check if a svn command needs authentication

Tags: ruby, windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any possible way to check if a SVN update needs authentication or not?

**Scenario :** I have written a ruby GUI app which updates SVN repositories (from a static path) in a scheduled manner. This executes as a windows service. Also have tortoisesvn installed.

In ruby when I execute

`svn update local_path_to_repository --username user --password password` in my script then it works fine as I am passing the username & password with the update command.

But, tortoisesvn saves the password (by caching password, using standard Windows cryptography services to encrypt the password on disk) when I checkout the repository for the first time so I don't necessarily need to pass the username and password every time. Thus I just have `svn update local_path_to_repository` in my script.

**Issue:** This works fine until I change my LDAP password. Once my LDAP password is changed all the repository fails to get updated as it is requesting for the new password but there is no user interface for passing the new password.

I need to build the username and password UI only when svn updates needs those credentials but not always. How do I achieve this?

> Update : Reading from the SVN [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache). I Understood that:

1. The client checks whether the user specified any credentials as command-line options (--username and/or --password). If not, or if these options fail to authenticate successfully, then
2. The client looks up the server's hostname, port, and realm in the runtime auth/ area, to see if the user already has the appropriate credentials cached. If not, or if the cached credentials fail to authenticate, then
3. Finally, the client resorts to prompting the user (unless instructed not to do so via the `--non-interactive` option or its client-specific equivalents).

But I did not find a way to check if authentication is required.

Can anyone please help me!

Comment: I do not see point with creating method that tries to authenticate user in any service. Do you know any service that does that ? You can always use STDERR and return code to find out if credentials are not correct.

Comment: @alkuzad : If I need to output the stderr then how do you do it in this case. I saw a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363512/getting-stderr-output-fails-when-svn-authenticaion-needed) with the same issue. Hope you can answer it there.

Comment: Use open3 module http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html or redirect stderr to stdout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally found a work around by doing:

```
output = `svn update "#{repo_path}" --non-interactive 2>&1`
check_authentication = output.include?("Authentication failed")
```

if `check_authentication` returns `true` meaning authentication has failed then I build the GUI for entering the new password and send it to the user.