# Getting STDERR output fails when SVN authenticaion needed

Tags: ruby, svn

I am trying to do a `svn update` command but as I have not passed the username and password with this command it asks me for those credentials. But I need to record the STDERR output of this command.

This is what is happening now :

```
record = `svn update 2>&1`
```

It outputs :

```
Authentication realm: <https://url_of_repository:443> url_of_repository SVN Repository
Username:
```

And it stops execution as its expecting the user to type credentials. But I would like to record the above output as a string in a variable so that I can pass the username and password to it. How do I do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by passing the `--non-interactive` argument with your command so that it does not prompt for authentication credentials.

So in your case :

```
output = `svn update "#{repo_path}" --non-interactive 2>&1`

check_authentication = output.include?("Authentication failed")
```

The `check_authentication` will return `true` if authentication failed.